# potential bug in superslides jquery addon?

Tags: jquery, css

I've just setup a page with a footer that includes a news ticker and a clock. I've got the slider working using superslides addon but i'm not sure if this is a bug or an error in my coding.

When the transition happens it covers half of the footer. I've uploaded the code at the following location to show the problem.

http://discoveryschoolstrust.org.uk/signage

**HTML**

```
  <div id="slides">
<div class="slides-container">
  <img src="images/people.jpeg" alt="Cinelli">
  <img src="images/surly.jpeg" width="1024" height="682" alt="Surly">
  <img src="images/cinelli-front.jpeg" width="1024" height="683" alt="Cinelli">
  <img src="images/affinity.jpeg" width="1024" height="685" alt="Affinity">
</div>
  </div>

<div id="footer">
 <div id="tickernews-container">

                    <ul id="tickernews" style="height: 60px; overflow: hidden;">

                        <div id="time"><span class="hour"></span></div>

                    <li style="margin-top: 0px;">
                            Fully customizable to every kind of vertical scrolling need.
                        </li><li style="margin-top: 0px;">
                            Light-weight and optimized JQuery plugin.
                        </li><li style="margin-top: 0px;">
                            A powerful, flexible and animated vertical news ticker plugin.
                        </li><li style="margin-top: 0px;">
                            Provides hight flexibility thanks to numerous callbacks &amp; methods.
                        </li></ul>
                </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/prism.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>   
<script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script> 
</body>
```

**CSS for Footer**

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
margin-bottom: 60px; 
}
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: simply enough just add a z-index to #footer

Comment: brilliant, i had never heard of z-index before. If you want to put it into an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the slider as it transitions has a higher z-index than the footer. All positioned elements can have a z-index set, making it appear higher or lower in the order of things.

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    z-index: 2;
}
```